# Android DataBinding.setContentView returns null

Tags: android, data-binding, ondemand

I created an app which is used as core for onDemand delivery.

One of the module have dataBinding enabled and when I start an activity from that module the app crashes with

> java.lang.NullPointerException

> ActivityLoginToVaultBinding binding =
> DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this,
> R.layout.activity_login_to_vault);

binding is returning null.

the layout activity_login_to_vault contains  as parent.

I need to mentions that is happening only for on demand delivery.

Comment: Were you able to resolve it?

Comment: @Surekha, I didn't found a solution and I was forced to remove DataBinding from the project. I replaced DataBinding with ViewBinding and it worked.

Comment: OK, thank you for your quick response.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the culprit in my onDemand module's AndroidManifest.xml. I initially had it as false when the binding nullPointer happened. Changing it to true, fixed the issue!

```
<dist:fusing dist:include="true" />
```